# How does pg_restore handle GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY columns?

Tags: postgresql

If I `pg_restore --data-only` into a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id int4 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    bar varchar
);
```

what happens to the `id` column? Is the `GENERATED ALWAYS` ignored and the ids from the `pg_dump` file inserted, or are new ids generated?

The [`pg_restore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/app-pgrestore.html) docs say, under the `--data-only` flag:

> Table data, large objects, and sequence values are restored, if present in the archive.

Does "sequence values" here include `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`?

I'm using Postgres 11 but it would be interesting to know if this behaviour has been the same since all generally supported versions (>=9.5).

Comment: "*Does "sequence values" here include GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY?*"  as `identity` columns use a sequence in the background, I would very much expect that.

Answer (score 2):

With `INSERT`, you need to use `OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE` if you want to overrule the default value from the identity column, but with `COPY` there are no such restrictions.

That makes it simple for `pg_dump`. Here is an example of what a dump of a table with identity column looks like:

```
/* section = pre-data */

CREATE TABLE laurenz.identity (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    value text NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE laurenz.identity ALTER COLUMN id ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (
    SEQUENCE NAME laurenz.identity_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1
);

/* section = data */

COPY laurenz.identity (id, value) FROM stdin;
1   one
2   two
3   three
-10 weird
-5  also weird
\.

/* section = post-data */

SELECT pg_catalog.setval('laurenz.identity_id_seq', 3, true);
```